# How to calculate the score for a whole word in my Scrabble game?

Tags: python

I can get the number from one letter but not for the whole word.
How would I do this?

This was my current result:

```
Enter a word: python  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "program.py", line 11, in <module>  
    print(SCORES[word])  
KeyError: 'python'
```

This is the code I tried:

```
SCORES = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4,
'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1,
'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1,
's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8,
'y': 4, 'z': 10,}

word = input('Enter a word: ')
print(SCORES[word])
```

This is what I want to get:

```
Enter a word: python
14
```

Comment: You need a for-loop to go through the letters and sum up their values.

Comment: `for letter in word:` will loop through each letter in the word. You could do that, repeatedly adding the score for each letter to a `total` variable (which you'd initialize to `0` before the loop`).

Comment: @Blorgbeard  and michael, thanks guys!

Comment: You could also consider using `sum` with a list comprehension: `sum([SCORES[ch] for ch in word])`

(list comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because 'python' is not a valid key in your `SCORES` dictionary.

To overcome this, you will need to look up each letter in the word one at a time. The easiest way to do so is with a for loop:

```
SCORES = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4,
'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1,
'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1,
's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8,
'y': 4, 'z': 10,}

word = input('Enter a word: ')

word_score = 0
for letter in word:
    word_score += SCORES[letter]

print(word_score)
```

Comment: just figured it out as you sent this, thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the little gray checkmark to the left of the answer.